# Adding a Javascript slideshow to the home page

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to add a Javascript slide show to my WordPress home page. In my theme folder I have a js folder and then in that I have `jquery.cross-slide.min.js` and `jquery.min.js`.

This is what I have and what I'm pasting into my post area:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cross-slide.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function() {
crossSlide({
sleep: 3,
fade: 1
}, [
{ src: 'images/slideshows/block1.jpg' },
{ src: 'images/slideshows/block2.jpg' },
{ src: 'images/slideshows/block3.jpg' }
])
});
</script>
```

If I paste this into a WordPress page throught the HTML editor it doesn't work. Please could you check for errors and advice.

Answer (score 1):

You pasted this in the regular post editor, where you also type your post content? This will not work, the editor filters out invalid HTML, like Javascript. I recommend you install one of the numerous slider gallery plugins and add your images via the existing gallery functionality.

Comment: Script tags go in the document head, and should be registered/enqueued using `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`, and then hooked into the document head, ideally at the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Answer (score 0):

@michael - hi,
you just forgot to connect this function to an element as you do in jQuery

```
 $('#crossslide').crossSlide(
   //code
  )
```

you may read [this](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/crossslide-jquery-plugin-test-348.html) for help

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out the [Cross Slide Cross Fade](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/crossslide-jquery-plugin-for-wordpress/) Plugin by christopherross.